# Is there a way to make Dashboards with Prometheus datasources responsible/loadable even when one of the datasources is down?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

***Problem:***

I have a dashboard in **Grafana** which monitors the healthiness of my monitoring services: *Prometheis, Alertmanagers, Pushgateways and Grafana* itself. It shows simple **Up/Down** status of these services in **Singlestat panels**.

When one of my Premetheus (I have one in each datacenter) is down, Singlestat panel which is backed with this Prometheus as a datasource **is loading 30s, until it shows *"Request error"***.

Even worse, when I want to have only one panel for each Prometheus instance and combine results from all Prometheis that monitor them (Prometheis in my setup monitor each other). For this I use ***--mixed--*** data source, and in this case, when one of used datasources is down **Singlestat panel loads forever**, and as down datasource is added in all my Singlestat panels for Prometheis, all these panels load forever.

Also when one of Prometheis stops working, I have a very long loading time of some Grafana pages:
 **Configuration -> Datasources** 
and
 **Dashboards -> Home**. 
But this is not always, sometimes it loads normally.

***Investigations:***

I investigated **Query timeout** in Grafana datasource (set it for 1s), but without any effect on this problem.

I have also tried to add **datasource variable**. It solves the problem only partially and I am not satisfied with it:

I have a combo box with datasources in Dashboard and Singlestat panel for each Prometheus backed with this variable dastasource. Problem is that I have to change through all the Prometheis in a combo box to see the whole picture for Prometheus services.

Similar it is possible to create Singlestat panels for all combinations of datasources and Prometheus instances (in my case 3 x 3 panels) but it is not intuitive and gets worse and worse with each Prometheus servers I will add in the future.

***Question:***

**Is there any way how to handle unreachable datasources, that dashboards will continue to work?**

Maybe I have to add some component to my setup, but I think it should be done in Grafana (although it seems it is not possible).

Comment: Did you have a look at [Thanos](https://thanos.io/) ? It may be overkill but would provide a unified view.